# Twilio react native accept call when the app is killed

Tags: react-native, twilio, voip

I have react native voip app, it uses react-native-twilio-phone and all subsequent required packages (callkeep, voip notifications etc).
Everything works pretty smoothly except last bit: when the app is killed, I am unable to accept a call. Voip notification gets through, wakes the app I tap accept, twilio instance gets initialized however it does not have any calls within this object.
Calls do work if the app is in background (not killed).

I tried different combinations of npm packages.
Chatgpt didn't give me any info.
I tried initializing twilio as soon as possible in the app with no network requests. Also I tried to register device right in AppDelegate file, still no luck.